# JqueryUI menu hover behavior extend

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Right now I have a scenario that I want to leverage the JqueryUI menu to render my dropdown menu, but my page is a responsive page which means in the desktop view JqueryUI menu works very well that submenu will show up when I hover its parent item. But when it comes to the mobile view, I want to disable hover behavior and enable click behavior which means if I hover it, the submenu will not show up until I click it. So does anyone know how to handle this scenario? Thanks

Comment: how will you hover in mobile device?

Comment: Samsung can hover on their smarphone haha. Did you try to run your website on a smartphone before asking your question?

Comment: You can just resize your browser to imitate the mobile view, that's the point.

Comment: Yeah view, touch your screen and try to hover over the menu then. You can only get the view of your webpage by resizing it but not how is the interactivity on a phone. You don't hover your finger over the menu on a smartphone you click it. It's like your mouse would be teleported on the menu. You don't have this ability only by resizing your screen on your computer

Comment: Fiddler can help you developing on your phone and check how hover works. There's also chrome plugins that can 'stream' your webpage to a phone. I've used this with ASP.Net give it a try